# Add an attribute to identify each row in a WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, attributes, row

I use a `DataGrid` to show the data from a table in database using the binding mechanism. I need to identify each row by a specific *ukey*

Is it possible to add an attribute in a row with my own value (the ukey) and after that can find the `DataGrid` Row by this ukey?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found that is possible to create unlimited `properties` for a `DataGrid` by using an attached property.

But I'm not sur if it's possible to find immediately a `Row` in the `DataGrid` by the created property or if I have to foreach each `Row` in `DataGrid` to find it ?

Comment: You can if you create a dictionary in C#. The key is the tag and the value is the row index of the Data Grid.

Comment: Ok it's a good idea, but I fill my DataGrid with binding, how can I fill a dictionnary ?

Comment: You would have a shadow dictionary that you initialize where the key is the tag and the value is the index into the DataGrid. You initialize this shadow dictionary whenever the DataGrid is updated.